# Process & thread scheduling overhead

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading

There are a few things I don't quite understand when it come to scheduling:

1. I assume each process/thread, as long as it is CPU bound, is given a time window. Once the window is over, it's swapped out and another process/thread is ran. Is that assumption correct? Are there any ball park numbers how long that window is on a modern PC? I'm assuming around 100 ms? What's the overhead of swapping out like? A few milliseconds or so?
2. Does the OS schedule by procces or by an individual kernel thread? It would make more sense to schedule each process and within that time window run whatever threads that process has available. That way the process context switching is minimized. Is my understanding correct?
3. How does the time each thread runs compare to other system times, such as RAM access, network access, HD I/O etc?
4. If I'm reading a socket (blocking) my thread will get swapped out until data is available then a hardware interrupt will be triggered and the data will be moved to the RAM (either by the CPU or by the NIC if it supports DMA) . Am I correct to assume that the thread will not necessarily be swapped back in at that point to handle he incoming data?

I'm asking primarily about Linux, but I would imagine the info would also be applicable to Windows as well.

I realize it's a bunch of different questions, I'm trying to clear up my understanding on this topic.

Comment: The scheduling frequency is set at kernel compile-time, so it can vary from system to system. Swapping is controlled via the `swappiness` setting, again this also varies. Not a full answer, but I hope it helps :)

Comment: It does help. At least I know what to google for :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I assume each process/thread, as long as it is CPU bound, is given a time window. Once the window is over, it's swapped out and another process/thread is ran. Is that assumption correct? Are there any ball park numbers how long that window is on a modern PC? I'm assuming around 100 ms? What's the overhead of swapping out like? A few milliseconds or so?

No. Pretty much all modern operating systems use pre-emption, allowing interactive processes that suddenly need to do work (because the user hit a key, data was read from the disk, or a network packet was received) to interrupt CPU bound tasks.

> Does the OS schedule by proces or by an individual kernel thread? It would make more sense to schedule each process and within that time window run whatever threads that process has available. That way the process context switching is minimized. Is my understanding correct?

That's a complex optimization decision. The cost of blowing out the instruction and data caches is typically large compared to the cost of changing the address space, so this isn't as significant as you might think. Typically, picking which thread to schedule of all the ready-to-run threads is done first and process stickiness may be an optimization affecting which core to schedule on.

> How does the time each thread runs compare to other system times, such as RAM access, network access, HD I/O etc?

Obviously, threads have to run through a very large number of RAM accesses because switching threads requires a large number of such accesses. Hard drive and network I/O are generally slow enough that a thread that's waiting for such a thing is descheduled.

Fast SSDs change things a bit. One thing I'm seeing a lot of lately is long-treasured optimizations that use a lot of CPU to try to avoid disk accesses can be worse than just doing the disk access on some modern machines!

Comment: I was wondering about that too - designing some threads to be CPU heavy, while others to be IO heavy vs mixing CPU / IO and letting the scheduler figure out the right mix.